# How to change the spacing in latexit for Times New Roman font?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, spacing

I've successfully changed the font used in Latexit (equation creator) to Times New Roman by changing the engine to xelatex and by adding this to my preamble:

```
\usepackage{mathspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode} 
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin){Times New Roman}
```

Sidenote: I've left off 'Greek' in my \setmathsfont because alpha and 'a' look identical in Times New Roman.  Now my problem - All superscripts are nearly on top of their variables.  I'm constantly using \,:

```
T^\,2
```

for example. Is there a way to change the default spacing?  or automatically use \, every time I have a ^ ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider to use the `newtxmath` package for a math version of Times font face (in LaTeX)

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

or switch to the XITS Math font (in XeLaTeX)

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```